# Android which Intent Flag should be used for ActivityGroup?

Tags: android, android-intent, flags, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have a `TabActivity` and the first tab is an `ActivityGroup` and I'm using the code below for this;

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
        Intent intent;
        Resources resources = getResources();

        intent = new Intent(MyTabActivity.this, MyActivityGroup.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab1", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        tabSpec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        intent = new Intent(MyTabActivity.this, SecondTab.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Tab2", resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        tabSpec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

And in my `ActivityGroup`, I want to go another `Activity` after `button` click therefore I'm using the code below:

```
public class MyActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup
{
    private Button button;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {           
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivityGroup.this, FirstActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("firstActivity", intent).getDecorView();
                setContentView(view);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It works but there is a problem, when I click the first tab while in the `FirstActivity`, I can not go to `MyActivityGroup`. But for example, after clicking `SecondTab`, if I click first tab, I can go to `MyActivityGroup`.

To solve this problem, I think I should change the Intent flag, but I couldn't manage it. Please help me.

Comment: Like I said, if you are within the first tab and 1 level deeper, the tabhost doesn't refresh the activitygroup and goes to the root of the group. You have to do I said, with an onclicklistener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show me some more? I had it implemented like this:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(getParent(), SomeClass.class);

    View view = SomeActivityGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager()  
    .startActivity("SomeClass", i  
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
    .getDecorView();  

    // Again, replace the view  
    SomeActivityGroup.group.replaceView(view);
```

Do you also want to see the activitygroup itself?

Ok, here it is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class SomeActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {

    View rootView;

    // Keep this in a static variable to make it accessible for all the nested
    // activities, lets them manipulate the view
    public static SomeActivityGroup group;

    // Need to keep track of the history if you want the back-button to work
    // properly, don't use this if your activities requires a lot of memory.
    private ArrayList<View> history;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
        group = this;

        // Start the root activity within the group and get its view
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("SomeActivity", new Intent(this, RootActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();

        // Replace the view of this ActivityGroup
        replaceView(view);
    }

    public void replaceView(View v) {
        // Adds the old one to history
        if (history.size() == 0) {
            if (rootView != null) {
                history.add(rootView);
                rootView = null;
            }
        }
        history.add(v);
        // Changes this Groups View to the new View.
        setContentView(v);
    }

    public void back() {
        try {
            if (history.size() > 0) {
                if (history.size() == 1) {
                    rootView = history.get(0);
                }
                history.remove(history.size() - 1);
                setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            SomeActivityGroup.group.back();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the ActivityGroup. I would like to mention that ActivityGroup is deprecated in ICS. It's better to use Fragments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As far as I understand, your code mentions back to ActivityGroup. But I also have one problem, due to your code, when I'm in RootActivity and click the tab, I can not go to SomeActivityGroup. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why not? I go to ActivityGroup from the RootActivity, which is shown in the first code example of my answer.

Comment: OK, I couldn't explain my problem exactly. In MyActivityGroup after button click, I'm going to FirstActivity. And I'm using the code in my question. Then, when I'm in FirstActivity, clicking tab does not move to MyActivityGroup. But when I'm in FirstActivity, clicking another tabs is working and after another tab, when I click the first tab I can go to MyActivityGroup. Why I couldn't go to MyActivityGroup directly from FirstActivity?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then it's something entirely different. You want to go to the RootActivity from within a tab. Check my other answer.

Comment: what is  back()  method do here ?

Comment: Handles the backstack of activities in the group. See comments above history.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the first tab, then this should be set in the

```
public class Tabhost extends TabActivity {
```

..

```
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0) {
                // tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); // UGLY!!
                // tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); // Had this before, but replaced it with :
                SomeActivityGroup.group.onResume();
            } else {
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

...